# Find an entire and not constant function such that $f(\lvert z\rvert=1) = i$

Tags: complex-analysis

I had an exam and there was a question:

> find, if exist, an entire and not constant function $f(z)$, so that for every $\lvert k\rvert=1$, $f(k) = i$.
>   if not exist - explain why.

I had no direction here.. How do you solve it?

Comment: Do you know the identity principle ?

Comment: or that the zeros of a non-constant analytic function are isolated, considering $g(z) = f(z)-i$..

Comment: @Hmm. yes I know it

Comment: Can  you now see the solution ?

Comment: @Hmm. I don't..
if I define $g(z) = f(z) - i$, then I get that $g(|z| = 1)=0$

Comment: A holomorphic function can't vanish at an uncountable set of points in its domain, for any uncountable subset of $\mathbb{C}$ has at least one accumulation point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**METHODOLOGY $1$:**

If $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ is analytic inside the unit disk, then we have $\nabla^2 u(x,y)=\nabla^2 v(x,y)=0$ for $x^2+y^2<1$.

Note that if in addition, $f(z)=i$ on the unit disk, then the problem is equivalent to the pair of interior [Dirichlet Problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_problem)

$$\begin{align}
\nabla^2 u(x,y)&=0, \,\,x^2+y^2<1\\\\
u(x,y)&=0,\,\,x^2+y^2=1 \tag 1
\end{align}$$

and

$$\begin{align}
\nabla^2 v(x,y)&=0, \,\,x^2+y^2<1\\\\
v(x,y)&=1,\,\,x^2+y^2=1 \tag 2
\end{align}$$

The unique solutions to $(1)$ and $(2)$ are trivially $u(x,y)=0$ and $v(x,y)=1$

Therefore, repeating this line for the exterior Dircihlet problem, the only entire function $f(z)$ with $f(z)=i$ on the unit circle is $f(z)=i$ for all $z$.

---

**METHODOLOGY $2$:**

Another way forward as suggested by @user1952009 is to apply [Cauchy's Integral Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem)

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{f(z')}{z'-z}\,dz' \tag 3$$

for $z$ inside the region for which $C$ is the boundary.

If $C$ is the unit circle on which $f(z)=i$, then for $|z|<1$ we find

$$\begin{align}
f(z)&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{i}{z'-z}\,dz' \\\\
&=i 
\end{align}$$

Note that [Cauchy's Integral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem#Statement_of_theorem) guarantees that for $|z|>1$

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{f(z')}{z'-z}\,dz'=0 \tag 4$$

Applying $(3)$ to a contour $C_R=\{z': |z'|=R>1\}$ and for $z$ such that $1<|z|<R$, and exploiting $(4)$, we find

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{C_R} \frac{f(z')}{z'-z}\,dz'=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{f(z')}{z'-z}\,dz'=i$$

Inasmuch as $R>1$ is arbitrary, we conclude immediately that $f(i)=i$ for all $z$.  And we are done!

Comment: @user1952009, this IS complex analysis.

Comment: @Hmm : I don't agree the uniqueness of the solution to the Dirichlet problem is the expected answer in a complex analysis course

Comment: @user1952009, it is highly regarded as one of the most important problems in complex analysis, and is covered in a year's course almost everywhere I know. In any case, please let the OP decide which answer he/she prefers.

Comment: @Hmm : not sure why you defend him, and in any complex analysis course I saw, what you call the identity principle is proven from the isolated zeros theorem, or the Taylor series (and the fact that all the derivatives of $f-g$ vanish at $z_0$). harmonic functions and the Dirichlet problem are mentioned only a long time after

Comment: and here the curve where $f(z)$ is constant is a closed contour, so we can even use the Cauchy integral formula (equivalent to the Dirichlet problem solution uniqueness but more adapted to a complex analytic function)

Comment: In any case, the approach here uses a result that is perfectly applicable.  Are you suggesting that one cannot appeal to results that simply don't fit your paradigm?  That sentiment seems to exhibit hubris.

Comment: @user1952009 And that will work too.  Consider posting that as an alternative and I will up vote it.  -Mark ... as you evidently knew.  ;-))

Comment: @user1952009 I've edited to add as another approach, the way forward that you suggested.  And I have given you an homage.  -Mark

Comment: : D tks for the homage

Comment: @user1952009 Not at all.  Your comments were useful and I consider you a friend here!